# usb-creator fails - cannot generate usb disk

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb, 14.10

Using Kubuntu 14.10 64Bit, to reproduce

1. select Kubuntu 14.10 64bit ISO image
2. use a USB key of 8Gb or more (tried VARIOUS BRAND)
3. select erase disk
4. assign 4Gb for the persistent disk
5. start the operation

The progress stops when it says creating persistent file 99%
From here nothing happens

I also posted as bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1411539

*Anyone is experiencing this problem?*

Comment: I always use unetbootin.  Never had any problems...  Does the md5sum check out?

Comment: Tried also unebootin with the same results. Also updated the bug. Mybe something related to my hardware? It is a Santech C37 http://www.santech.eu/notebook/c37-series

Comment: you didn't answer the 2nd question: Does the md5sum check out?  do a `md5sum Whatever.iso` and it should give you a number. (if it doesn't `sudo apt-get coreutils`) what is the name of your iso and the number?

Comment: You are right: md5sum gives an error: I'll download again and will try again  `ls -la
totale 1103248
drwxrwxrwx 5 root  root        4096 dic 20 09:14 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mirto mirto 1129709568 nov 13 20:00 kubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mirto mirto        131 nov 13 19:18 MD5SUMS
mirto@mirto-P650SE:/Mio/ISO/kubuntu/14.10$ md5sum --check MD5SUMS
kubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
md5sum: kubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso: File o directory non esistente
kubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso: apertura o lettura NON RIUSCITA
md5sum: ATTENZIONE: 1 file elencato non può essere letto
)`

Comment: Converted to an answer... Prego! ;-)

Comment: Bellissimo: due italiani che si parlano in inglese! :-)))

Answer (score 0):

***In above case it's a [bug in Kubuntu 14.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1411539), so in this particular case the below procedure will not work!***

**Workaround to circumvent the bug:** use the below procedure on another machine not running Kubuntu 14.10:

Most of the time when a DVD/USB burnt from an [official release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) doesn't work, is because of a bad download.

Therefore type the following command:

```
apt-get install coreutils
md5sum kubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

(above an example for Kubuntu, your exact `.iso` file name will differ) and you will get a number back like this: `a48e3fc0c36a735b2c77e430d985e1e0`

Compare that to the [official Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) and if it's different (you'll see it immediately, that's why I provided a failed hash above) just download it again...

Comment: Sorry no luck (english for all the other)

Comment: Sorry no luck (english for all the others).  verified the md5sum  created a fresh fat32 filesystem on the usb key.  launched unetbootin selecting the iso image.  it stalls on step 3 installing bootloader.  gave up after 15 minutes on step 3 without messages.  On other machines/distribution unetbooin works normally